# How to fix PHP 7.2 Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in errors.php?

Tags: php, web, backend

My script is-

```
<?php  if (count($errors) > 0) : ?>
  <div class="error">
        <?php foreach ($errors as $error) : ?>
          <p><?php echo $error ?></p>
        <?php endforeach ?>
  </div>
<?php  endif ?>
```

The error I get is `Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`.

I'm using `PHP 7.2` on Apache2.

Comment: Your code doesn't show how `$errors` is set, it's probably either not set or is a string.  When using something like this it is usually best to initialise the value at the start to an empty array - `$errors = [];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, `Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`, the `$errors` should be an array.

In your case, it might be empty. So before using `count()` you should always check it implements a Countable interface.

I assume you are trying to iterate an `Array` and for that I first check the `$errors` is an array using `is_array()`.

```php
<?php  if (is_array($errors) && count($errors) ) : ?>
  <div class="error">
        <?php foreach ($errors as $error) : ?>
          <p><?php echo $error ?></p>
        <?php endforeach ?>
  </div>
<?php  endif ?>
```

You may also need to look at `is_countable()`, link below:

PHP Official Documentation:

[PHP count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

[PHP is_countable()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-countable.php)

[PHP is_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)